# Mutated Objects :'(

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Hello? I wanted to display an array of objects in a data table. I get my array of objects from my redux and map them to replace the statuses. But somehow my redux is updated too. I tried immutable copy `Object.assign`, `[...]`. Please help.

```
const convertNumberToJobUnit = (data) => {
    const Agents = Object.assign({}, data)
    return Agents.totalAgents.map(item => {
        switch(item.worker_status) {
        case 1: item.worker_status = 'Үндсэн'
            break
        case 2: item.worker_status = 'Гэрээт'
            break
        default: break
        }
        switch(item.worker_level) {
        case 1:  item.worker_level = 'New Staff'
            break
        case 2:  item.worker_level = 'Normal'
            break
        case 3:  item.worker_level = 'Good'
            break
        case 4:  item.worker_level = 'Very Good'
            break
        default: break
        }
        // item.clickEvent = () => clickEvent(item.device_id)
        item.created_date = dateConvert(item.created_date)
        Agents.jobList.map(jobItem => {
            if(item.job_id === jobItem.id) {
                item.job_id = jobItem.job_name
            }
            return jobItem
        })
        Agents.unitList.map(unitItem => {
            if(item.organizition_unit_id === unitItem.id) {
                item.organizition_unit_id = unitItem.unit_name
            }
            return unitItem
        })
        return item
    })
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Where do you use `Object.assign`?

Comment: @David that was wrong code. I updated it

Comment: `Object.assign` only copies values and hence the array you are iterating on will still maintain it's reference. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do deep cloning and `Object.assign` doesn't do deep cloning.

Replace this line `const Agents = Object.assign({}, data)` with `const Agents = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`.

[For more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Niraj's Solution. Avoid mutating objects when you use array `map`. Create new objects on map function return values. As seen in below, you can use `find` and update value instead of map. Hope this helps.

```
const convertNumberToJobUnit = data => {
  const Agents = Object.assign({}, data);
  return Agents.totalAgents.map(item => {
    let worker_status;
    let worker_level;
    switch (item.worker_status) {
      case 1:
        worker_status = "Үндсэн";
        break;
      case 2:
        worker_status = "Гэрээт";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    switch (item.worker_level) {
      case 1:
        worker_level = "New Staff";
        break;
      case 2:
        worker_level = "Normal";
        break;
      case 3:
        worker_level = "Good";
        break;
      case 4:
        worker_level = "Very Good";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    const job = Agents.jobList.find(jobItem => item.job_id === jobItem.id);
    const unit = Agents.unitList.find(
      unitItem => item.organizition_unit_id === unitItem.id
    );

    return {
      ...item,
      created_date: dateConvert(item.created_date),
      job_id: job ? job.job_name : item.job_id,
      organizition_unit_id: unit ? unit_name : item.organizition_unit_id,
      worker_status,
      worker_level
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: I just saw this and find actually helps. Thank you